# Moving WP blog to Tumblr but still use old WP server's images?

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, cname-record

I've successfully moved my old WP blog that I hosted on my server to a Tumblr blog by using the CNAME to point to it.

However, all of the Tumblr blog's photos are still hosted on my old WP blog, so they are not showing up anymore.

**How can I maintain the redirect to Tumblr except for photos (png/jpg or really any file, because the only accesses for a file would be an image)?**

Could I use a RewriteCond in my htaccess, or will that be overridden by the CNAME record from my blog subdomain to Tumblr's?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. CNAMEing the domain delegates it to Tumblr's servers, you have no control over what it serves. You'd have to rehost your images via Tumblr, or host your old blog subdomain on a new subdomain and update all your posts' images to that new subdomain.

Comment: I'll take option 2. Genius. Thanks!